# systemd vs xinetd

Tags: systemd, xinetd, tftpd

I have a CentOS 7 system which uses systemd, and I want to start a tftp server.  I'm confused about the right way to do this.  I've seen some posts that say install xinetd and launch it from there (like pre-systemd), and other posts that say enable tftp.socket

Is xinetd just a bridge to systemctl socket which will eventually go away?

If so, where would I place my tftp configuration settings (since the xinetd tftp file would not be used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, is not a bridge to `systemctl`, it's just the traditional daemon.
So you can choose whether you start `tftp` with `xinetd` or with systemd socket.

Nice explanation on systemd blog: 
http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html.